# second request and later fail $request->ajax()

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I do have foreach loop for display each in blade . I use ajax for send request to controller, but I encounter some problem the first loop ajax work fine and the second and other response black b/c in controller check the request is ajax. I don’t know why request is not ajax, any help thanks.

### Blade file

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST','route' => ['conference.storeRate', $conference->id], 'id' => "conferenceRate"]) !!}

<div style="margin: 5px">
   <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Review</button>
</div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

### script

```
$("#conferenceRate").submit(function(e){
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
            var post_url = $(this).attr("action"); //get form action url
            var request_method = $(this).attr("method"); //get form GET/POST method
            var form_data = $(this).serialize(); //Encode form elements for submission
            $.ajax({
                type:request_method,
                url:post_url,
                data:form_data,
                success:function(data){

                if($.isEmptyObject(data.error)){
                        $("#msg").show();
                        $("#msg").html("Successfuly Rated!!");
                        $("#msg").fadeOut(5000);

                 }else{
                  jQuery('.alert-danger').show();
                  jQuery('.alert-danger').html('<p>'+data.error+'</p>');
                  jQuery('.alert-danger').fadeOut(10000);

                    }


                       }//end success data function

                    });//end of ajax for get org

  });// end search 
</script>
```

### Controller

```
    public function conferenceStore(Request $request, $id)
    {
return response()->json($request->ajax()); // false 
        if($request->ajax())
        {
        }
}
```

My first loop working fine pass the check the request is ajax, but the other 2nd, 3rd loop value fail to response false while check the request id ajax

Comment: If I understand correctly, are you putting those forms inside a foreach? If so, you should change the id `'id' => "conferenceRate"`  of each form on each iteration

Comment: Or seeing what you're trying to do it might be better to use a class instead of an id

Comment: yes, form are inside foreach !! ```change the id 'id' => "conferenceRate" of each form on each iteration``` how can i do that, show me code, please!!

Comment: working fine thanks bro @porloscerrosΨ